# NSDate to NSString, then use substringToIndex, crash sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

in iOS6.x，it will crash sometimes:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:i * 24 * 3600 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

NSString *rtnDateString = [dateString substringToIndex:10];
```

sometimes, i will receieve follow crash message:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

i want to know why the length of the converted string from date using format "yyyy-MM-dd" is less than 10?

Comment: 1) What is the crash message? Which line crashes? 2) The 1st line is a bad way to calculate the next day. Not all days have 24 hours and not all hours have 3600 seconds.

Comment: The date format string contains an extra apostrophe `'` at the end. Please fix that and recheck.

Comment: @mengliu please add the information of your comment to the original Q.

Comment: when execute [datestring substringToIndex:10], the crash message is substringToIndex out of the bounds, it means the length of dateString less than 10

Comment: Before getting the substringToIndex to calculate the length of the  string

Comment: if you want date format like 2014-05-12 than no need extra apostrophe ' in your string you directly set format [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy - MM - dd"];

Comment: print the dateString log before it get crashed

Comment: What are you even trying to do? First of all, you adding days it seems, but there are better ways to do that (try your solution at 10 to Midnight and with i big enough to cross a daylight savings change. You'll probably end on a date you were not expecting. In other words, not every day is 24 hours long, some are 23, some 25 and, I believe, even other cases). Also, dateString would be expected to be 10 characters long - why the substringToIndex? rtnDateString should be identical to dateString...

Comment: @ThomasMüller, i think it's no necessary, because the dateString is from format date.

Comment: @ThomasMüller i knew there is a better way to get dateString with custom dateFormat. but, in some reason, i did not use it.
I want to know why the dateString from NSDate with dateFormat(yyyy - MM - dd) is less then 10 lenth..